# How to concatenate strings in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to get USERNAME and PASSWORD from the user and put them inside of a string.

```
var id = "1"
var pw = "password"
```

Here is my code:

```
parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string : "http://blablabla.com/UNAME&PW")!)!
```

But it creates this result:

```
"http://blablabla.com/\id\&\pw\"
```

How do I put the values of `id` and `pw` inside of a string?

Comment: "could not edit the link" Why not, what went wrong when you tried?

Comment: I'm trying that code

"http://blablabla.com\id\&\pw\"

Comment: This question is really unclear.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic cause of my English but someone got it Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Concat strings in swift you have two options:

```
let completeURL = "http://blablabla.com/\(usernameVar)&\(passwordVar)"

let completeURL = "http://blablabla.com/" + usernameVar + "&" + passwordVar
```

Comment: Note that convention states that variable names should start with a lowercase letter, and follow `camelCase`. For example, `completeURL` & `usernameVar` (although just `username` would be better)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer.